# ImportError persists after adding the path to PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, environment, pythonpath, sys.path

I get the following error while running some python code

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dspl.py", line 4, in 
    import base
ImportError: No module named base

The disp.py is in directory PERSISTENCE_LENGTH, as listed below. The disp.py imports few python scripts that are inside the directory UTILS (shown below). I added the path of imported directory (/home/vinay/oxDNA) to PYTHONPATH i.e.,export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/vinay/oxDNA/). There is a proper__init__.py file inside the UTILS directory.

disp.py is in the directory: /home/vinay/oxDNA/EXAMPLES/PERSISTENCE_LENGTH

disp.py is importing other modules that are in the directory: /home/vinay/oxDNA/UTILS

When I print sys.path, I can see that PYTHONPATH is okay. as shown below 
['', '/home/vinay', '/home/vinay/oxDNA/UTILS', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', )

Comment: Is it an `init.py` or an `__init__.py`?

Comment: Also it would be a good idea to add your file/directory structure and the import section in question.

Comment: Klaus, yes, that is__init__.py. Sorry, I am am new here, and I don't how to edit properly a question.

Comment: @user2964728 "Use the Force, Luke"(c) I mean, use the "edit" link.

Comment: If you are adding the full module path, that would be your problem. You put the directory that holds the module into PYTHONPATH. If the module path is `/home/user/mymodules/XYZ.__init__.py`, PYTHONPATH would be `/home/user/mymodules`

Comment: I added the PYTHONPATH as: export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/vinay/oxDNA/UTILS/

Comment: @user2964728: Since you haven't told us whether the `XYZ` directory is in that `UTILS` directory (and again, as ivan_pozdeev said, edit all of this into the question, don't just answer it in comments…), that doesn't tell us enough to debug the problem. Show us the directory structure and the actual code (ideally of a [stripped-down, minimal program that demonstrates the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Answer (score 0):

If your module is in a directory, rather than being a singled named file, then the directory is required to have a `__init__.py` file. The existence of this file makes the directory a module and then you can load from that module, the `__init__.py` can be empty but you can also have an entry in it of:

```
__all__ = ['component_name1', 'etc', 'etc']
```

If you do then the names listed in `__all__` are those that will be available after a `from mondule_name import *`

The normal practice is to have a meaningful name for the directory, e.g.: `my_utils' and for the components within the directory, e.g.: 'file_io.py' and you can then access the items within file_io as:

```
import my_utils
my_utils.file_io.functionA()
```

or

```
from my_utils import file_io
file_io.functionA()
```

or

```
from my_utils.file_io import functionA()
functionA()
```

Note that in the all above examples `functionA` has access to other functions within `file_io.py` and, if `file_io.py` has the appropriate imports, to other functions in other files in `my_utils`.

It is also important to remember that python **is** case dependent ***even on windows***.

Comment: Hi Steve, Other things are as you suggested except the last thing (from module_name import *). In my case it is: import module_name.